# Capture Column Groups?

Tags: notepad++

i have

> nbading|61144833f2af7519b9065b79c59fbab3408ff02af112824067d91449e63a1a16|1960879|gmedia',

i need

> nbading|61144833f2af7519b9065b79c59fbab3408ff02af112824067d91449e63a1a16

how to do that with regex

Answer (score 0):

Use Find/Replace Dialog:

- **Find What:** `^((([^\|]+\|?)){2})\|.*$`
- **Replace With:** `\1`
- Check **Regular Expression**
- Click **Replace All**

**Explanation:**

- at its core `([^\|]+\|?)` the re matches a sequence of characters that are not `|` followed by an optional `|`
- optional because you dont want the second pipe in your result
- `(...){2}` means two of such sequences
- `^( ... )\|.*$` means

  - that we anchor the match at the beginning of the line
  - then we put the two sequences in the first capturing group
  - and we require that a `|` follows the two sequences, thus the first optional pipe belongs to the first group and the second optional pipe does not belong to the second group
  - then we match everthing the follows in `.*`
- the replacement by `\1` discard the second pipe and everything that follows

Comment: thanks how to reserve lines can you please explain to when line1:line2 and i need line2:line1

Comment: @GothamCity Please give more detail: Do you want to switch every pair of lines? Does your input file have only two lines? Do you want to reverse every line. Please edit your question and add example input lines together with the expected output lines. At the moment I can see only one line.